# Why is my reducer returning undefined, React TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I am trying to setup my `Redux` store with React and `TypeScript` but it gives me an error that my `auth` reducer is `undefined`.

This is my **store.ts**:

```
import {Action, applyMiddleware, combineReducers, compose, createStore} from 'redux';
import { auth, IAuthState } from './Auth/reducer';
import { general, IGeneralState } from './General/reducer';

export interface IAppState {
    auth: IAuthState;
    general: IGeneralState;
}

export const rootReducer = () => combineReducers({
        auth: auth,
        general: general,
});

const store = createStore<IAppState, Action<any>, {}, {}>(
    rootReducer(),
    (window as any).__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ &&
    (window as any).__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
);

export { store };
```

This is my **auth reducer**:

```
import { User } from '../../interfaces/user.interface';
import { AuthActionTypes } from './actions';

export interface IAuthState {
    user: User;
    authenticated: boolean;
}

const initialState: IAuthState = {
    user: null,
    authenticated: true,
};

export const auth = (state: IAuthState = initialState, action: any): IAuthState => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case AuthActionTypes.Setuser:
            const { User } = action.payload;

            return {
                ...state,
                user: User
            };

        case AuthActionTypes.Logout:

            return {
                ...state,
                user: null,
                authenticated: false,
            };
    }
};
```

It gives me the error:

> Uncaught Error: Reducer "auth" returned undefined during
>   initialization. If the state passed to the reducer is undefined, you
>   must explicitly return the initial state. The initial state may not be
>   undefined. If you don't want to set a value for this reducer, you can
>   use null instead of undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only thing what you need to do is always return a value from the reducer, even if it is `null`.

The following fix will do the job:

```
export const auth = (state: IAuthState = initialState, action: any): IAuthState => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case AuthActionTypes.Setuser:
            const { User } = action.payload;

            return {
                ...state,
                user: User
            };

        case AuthActionTypes.Logout:

            return {
                ...state,
                user: null,
                authenticated: false,
            };
    }

    // this step was missing
    return state;
};
```

Few rules what you need to follow:

1. Always needs to be returning state, even if you did not change anything, even the value is just `null`.
2. You should not have return `undefined`.
3. If the state has changed, you need to replace it e.g.: `{...state, newValue: false}`.

From documentation:

> We return the previous state in the default case. It's important to return the previous state for any unknown action.

Read further: [Handling Actions](https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers#handling-actions)

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Reducer is a simple function that returns state no matter if it has changed or not. You are missing the default case in your reducer so just replace it with below :

```
export const auth = (state: IAuthState = initialState, action: any): IAuthState => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case AuthActionTypes.Setuser:
            const { User } = action.payload;

            return {
                ...state,
                user: User
            };

        case AuthActionTypes.Logout:

            return {
                ...state,
                user: null,
                authenticated: false,
            };

         default:                // this are 2 lines ive added
            return state
    }
};
```

Hope it helps. feel free for doubts

Answer (score -1):

You forgot to add the default case.

```js
export const auth = (state: IAuthState = initialState, action: any): IAuthState => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case AuthActionTypes.Setuser:
      const { User } = action.payload;

      return {
        ...state,
        user: User
      };

    case AuthActionTypes.Logout:

      return {
        ...state,
        user: null,
        authenticated: false,
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```